# How to manage table aliases in Laravel Query Builder functions from() and leftJoin()?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-query-builder

I have a complex query:

```
   $sql = "SELECT dateQ.selected_date, apiQ.no_of_error AS error 
            FROM ( 

                SELECT * from 
                (SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from 
                (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0, 
                (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1, 
                (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2, 
                (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3, 
                (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) v WHERE selected_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()

            ) 
            dateQ LEFT JOIN 
            (
                SELECT date(created_at) as ddate, COUNT(id) AS no_of_error 
                FROM `api_logs` 
                WHERE status_code <> 200 
                AND api_id = '" . $rowApi['id'] . "'
                AND created_at BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE() 
                GROUP BY date(created_at)
            ) 
            apiQ ON DATE(apiQ.ddate) = dateQ.selected_date GROUP BY dateQ.selected_date ORDER BY dateQ.selected_date DESC";
```

I want to split it using Laravel query builder.

The subquery:

```
   SELECT date(created_at) as ddate, COUNT(id) AS no_of_error 
   FROM `api_logs` 
   WHERE status_code <> 200 
        AND api_id = '" . $rowApi['id'] . "'
        AND created_at BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE() 
   GROUP BY date(created_at)
```

is modified like this:

```
$apiQ   = DB::table('api_logs')
               ->select('date(created_at) as ddate', DB::raw('COUNT(id) AS no_of_error'))
               ->where('api_id', $rowApi['id'])
               ->where('status_code', '<>', 200)
               ->whereRaw('created_at BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()')
               ->groupBy('date(created_at)');
```

Then the other subquery,

```
SELECT * from 
    (SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from 
    (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0, 
    (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1, 
    (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2, 
    (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3, 
    (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) 
    v WHERE selected_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

is modified like this:

```
 $dateQ  = DB::select('*')
           ->from("(SELECT adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3, 
                            (SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) v")
         ->whereRaw('selected_date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND CURDATE()');
```

Now I finally trying to build up the entire query, like this:

```
 $final= DB::select('dateQ.selected_date', 'apiQ.no_of_error AS error')
              ->from($dateQ, 'AS dateQ')
              ->leftJoin($apiQ, function($join){
                     $join->on(DB::RAW('DATE(apiQ.ddate'), '=', 'dateQ.selected_date')
                })
              ->groupBy('dateQ.selected_date')
              ->orderBy('dateQ.selected_date', 'DESC');
```

But I cannot make the appropriate work out for the aliases like 'dateQ and apiQ'.

Comment: You have a typo on the `leftJoin`, look after `$join->on(DB::RAW( HERE`. See that you have `DB::RAW('DATE(apiQ.ddate')` when it should be like `DB::RAW('DATE(apiQ.ddate)')`. I am not sure if it is a typo you have in your code or you just copy pasted wrongly. But that full query is CRAZY.

Comment: I suggest this is closed as "typo" for now - it appears to be abandoned.